# How to remove a document in Mongodb based on if there is a document that is newer

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, database

How can I make it so in my meteor web app when a document is inserted, a function automatically deletes any previous insertions into the database. Here is the code I've tried but it will not work:

```
if(SearchLobby.find({profile: Meteor.userId()}).count() > 1){

  var date1=SearchLobby.find().limit(1).sort({$natural:-1}).createdAt;

  if(SearchLobby.find({profile: Meteor.userId()}).createdAt != date1)
    SearchLobby.remove({profile: Meteor.userId()});
}
```

Not really sure how else to go about doing this, I didnt really expect this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with [Meteor Collection Hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) using `before.insert`-hook. On server do:

```
SearchLobby.before.insert(function(userId, doc) {
    SearchLobby.remove({profile:Meteor.userId()});
});
```

Comment: this crashes my app when I put it on the server... any ideas why? it says call method of insert is undefined

Comment: Did you install the package? `meteor add matb33:collection-hooks`